# python selenium multiple issues

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

When the browser opens it immediately closes unless there is a time.sleep() after it and im getting this error when trying to click a button

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="button"]"}
```

Heres my code:

```
import dhooks
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from dhooks import Webhook, Embed
import time
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

s=Service('/Users/pax/Desktop/Benzinga/chrome driver/chromedriver')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)
driver.maximize_window() 
driver.implicitly_wait(20) 
url='https://www.youtube.com/'
driver.get(url)
driver.find_element_by_id("button").click()
```